# Django: регистрация пользователя через vk

Tags: django, vkontakte-api

помогите разобраться с регистрацией на сайте (Django) через вконтакте. Как я понимаю, сначала нужно получить инфу о пользователе через api vk(имя-фамилия, id, email и т.д). Что дальше делать с этими данными? Использовать их для создания пользователя в БД django?

user=User.objects.create_user('foo', password='bar')

Но где брать пароль и что использовать в качестве имени?

Comment: Просто возьмите [python-social-auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth) и не изобретайте велосипед.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего для начала сделать новую модель, где вы будете хранить дополнительные данные (id профиля как минимум) и OneToOne на User.
Затем вам надо будет сделать свою страницу для регистрации, куда пользователя будет перенаправлять, и куда будут подставляться данные из профиля.
И там даете возможность пользователю написать логин и пароль.
Это наиболее удобно пользователям.
Ну и потом можно настроить вход в аккаунт на вашем сайте через ВК. 
[Здесь](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites) можете посмотреть как это делается.